# Making a laravel feed faster via better SQL fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

for a school project I've been making this feed of posts, stories, and groups. but I find it very slow.
and I was thinking on forcing some more processing on the SQL part instead of processing it on the php side

I'm using the search thingy from [nicolaslopezj](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable) . and that is fast as hell. So I'm olmost certain that it's the php code :)

And the algorithm isn't even great, so I could use another opinion/tips&tricks for the following code?

The thing that should be put in the FeedTransformer is an array of Post, Story and Group Models.
They then get transformed in a decent Json Output format. (there I do things like Post->User and that get's passed to a userTransformer, which asks for the username and such) So it's possible, by doing there things different it can be optimised as well.

```
public function feed() {
    // pagination stuff
    $perPage = 15;
    $page = (Input::has( 'page' )? Input::get( 'page' ) : 1);
    $offset = ( ( $page - 1 ) * $perPage );

    // feed start
    $feed = new Collection();
    // start arrays
    $posts = new Collection();
    $stories = new Collection();
    $groups = Auth::user()->groups;

    // check if user has friends
    if (Auth::user()->friends()->count() != 0) {
      // get from good relationship
      $friendCollection = Auth::user()->friends()->Where( 'relationShipStatus', '>', '50' );

      // get all posts
  $posts = Post::has( 'Stories', '=', 0 )->has( 'Group', '=', 0 )->whereIn(
    'user_id', $friendCollection->lists( 'id' )
  )->orWhere( 'user_id', Auth::user()->id )->has( 'Stories', '=', 0 )->has( 'Group', '=', 0 )->with('user')->get();

      // get those stories
      $stories = Story::whereIn(
        'user_id', $friendCollection->lists( 'id' )
      )->orWhere( 'user_id', Auth::user()->id )->get();
    }

    // merge together
    $posts->isEmpty() ?: $feed = $feed->merge( $posts );
    $stories->isEmpty() ?: $feed = $feed->merge( $stories );
    $groups->isEmpty() ?: $feed = $feed->merge( $groups );

    // sort by updated date
    $feed->isEmpty() ?: $feed = $feed->sortBy( 'updated_at' )->reverse();

    // apply pagination
    $userFeed = new Paginator( $feed->slice( $offset, $perPage, true )->all(), $feed->count(), $page );
    return $this->RespondWithPagination( $userFeed, $feed->count(), [ 'data' => FeedTransformer::transformCollection( $userFeed ) ] );
  }
```

all models can be found here: https://gist.github.com/285082ae6005a77e2c1e.git
Transformers can be found here: https://gist.github.com/cskiwi/c6d601bae12a45301a79

I already reduced the time down to about 3s. I could do some chaching, but I think the algoritm can be way better!

I tried adding `->with('')` tags, but those don't seem to be lowering the speed... (the call remains the same right?)

Comment: What exactly should the output be? Please provide more info. What data do you need?

Comment: Your transformers are running queries (gets and counts etc), your main bit of code runs unnecessary queries, you've got repeat bits of code like listing your friend collection, you're selecting all of your data then cutting it up and paginating it. Lots to look at